# How to offload old views to scripts from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

Looking for a quick and dirty way to archive some old views to plaintext scripts from a query. I've come up with this bit of SQL:

```
select
    SO.name as [ViewName],
    SM.definition as [ViewCode]
from
    sys.sql_modules SM,
    sys.objects SO
where
    SO.object_id = SM.object_id
    and SO.type = 'v'
    and ((SO.name like '%2BDeleted%')
        or (SO.name like '%ToBDeleted%')
        or (SO.name like '%ToBeDeleted%'))
```

What I would like to do is save a text file using the value of ViewName as the filename of each script (i.e., "[ViewName].sql"), with the contents of the corresponding value of ViewCode as the contents of that textfile.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where would you like to save these text files? On the Database Server?

Comment: No, just locally for now, until I find a long-term home. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: No problem, so what is it you are having issues with, can't you just open a DB connection through a console application and have it run your query, then select the ViewName for each result set, use that to create a .txt file and then write the ViewCode to that file using System.IO

Comment: Operative term is quick and dirty...  I'm in SSMS...  literally just starting a new job and don't yet have Visual Studio or other dev tools at my disposal. Only SSMS. If I can do it using only SQL, I'm good.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/

Comment: I need to write individual files, one for each row of my result set. Not one big file consisting of entire result set.

Comment: Looks like you want to do System.IO operations straight out of SQL Server, this looks like a good thing to read (https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/), and to get each individual View as it's own file, you could use a cursor to iterate your result set, and create a new file for each one.

Comment: We should have stopped joining in the where clause over a decade ago.

Comment: @SMor, the noise is unhelpful.

Comment: @RyanWilson, yes, the above query I wrote was fed into a cursor...  I still couldn't write the files in this manner as I did not have permissions to do so. Had to do a two step process ultimately (next comment).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to go to Tasks > Generate Scripts... then I named the files by prefixing the DB name in front. Archived after that. Worked for my purposes. Thanks to those who read/responded, trying to help.  :)